# Getting stuck while building DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to build dpdk version 21.05.

I did run `meson build` and then while running `ninja`, it gets stuck at

`[2030/2380] Compiling C object drivers/libtmp_rte_event_octeontx2.a.p/event_octeontx2_otx2_evdev.c.o`
and does not move forward.
What could cause such a behavior?

This is with:
ubuntu 20.04.1 x86_64
kernel 5.8.0-1041-aws
gcc 9.3.0
ninja 1.10.0
meson 0.59.0

and no cross compiling

Comment: can you share some details like Platform, OS, is it cross build, GCC version, meson-ninja version? are you going to use for `octeon` or x86 or arm platform?

Comment: can you disable octeon and try build?

Comment: @VipinVarghese how can I do that?

Comment: you can use meson option `-Ddisable_drivers=event/octeontx2,event/octeontx` as you have mentioned ninja is hung at oceteon eventdev build.. Hence the command sequence would be `meson -Ddisable_drivers=event/octeontx2,event/octeontx build; ninja -C build`

Comment: are there any updates from your end?

Comment: now I get 
```[2312/2343] Compiling C object app/test/dpdk-test.p/test_ring.c.o
FAILED: app/test/dpdk-test.p/test_ring.c.o
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs> for instructions.```

Comment: the DPDK libraries and PMD are compiled, the failure is coming from `test_ring` application. If you are using test_ring application you will need to fix this. Else you can use DPDK libraries as it is. I am can spend 10 minutes on skype to debug with you if you are interested? let me know if you are interested.

Comment: @Kviz are there any updates on rebuilding with octeon event drivers disabled. It will much easier to debug if you share your environment details like how many CPU cores, CPU arch and memory too

Answer (score 0):

Checked DPDK 21.05, on Host (24 CPU cores) and Guest (1GB RAM, 2 CPU) with Broadwel x86_64 qemu on Ubuntu 20.04

1. with event octeon - pass
2. with event octeon disabled - pass

```
[2565/2565] Linking target app/dpdk-test-acl. (octeon eventdev)

[2530/2530] Linking target drivers/librte_event_dpaa2.so.21.2. (without oceteon eventdev)
```

[EDIT based on the update via commenton Au 26 2021]

suggested @Kviz on building with `-Ddisable_drivers=event/octeontx2,event/octeontx` to skip the built with octeon eventdev instance. This is confirmed to be successful. Current failure as is on dpdk `test_ring` application.

Suggestion:

1. If the target is only DPDK libraries one can ignore the same and proceed using DPDK libraries.
2. But if the target is to run `dpdk-test for test_ring`, the issue needs to resolve by analysis of the cause of failure.

Note: as per the error log `gcc-7` but platform is `ubuntu 20.04.1 x86_64 kernel 5.8.0-1041-aws gcc 9.3.0` something is not proper.